# How to redirect an Apache backed proxy on elasticbeanstalk.com to a custom domain?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running an app in Elastic Beanstalk using Tomcat. I set up my own domain name that I've added as a CNAME alias of the `xyz.elasticbeanstalk.com` address for my environment and it all works well. What I'd like to do is redirect traffic accessing the site at `xyz.elasticbeanstalk.com` to my own domain name.

I thought I could do this using .ebextensions in my WAR file like this:

myapp.config:

```
container_commands:
    01_setup_rewrite:
        command: "cp .ebextensions/redirect_canonical.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/redirect_canonical.conf"
    02_apache_restart:
        command: /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

redirect_canonical.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

I've used similar mod_rewrite rules before in a `.htaccess` file and they worked well but because this is a mod_proxy I'm not sure if this is right (or if I can even put the rewrite command in the conf.d folder).

How can I configure it do redirect as I would like?

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end?

Answer (score 0):

From Mason G. Zhwiti's answer to the related question [How to get Elastic Beanstalk nginx-backed proxy server to auto-redirect from HTTP to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24297376/45773) I'd figure that you need to approach this in a similar fashion for Apache, e.g. something like this (Bash script omitted due to lack of time for actually testing it):

```
files:
  "/tmp/45_apache_redirect_canonical.sh":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash
      # TODO: create script that injects content of your 'redirect_canonical.conf' 
      #       into (presumably) '/etc/httpd/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf'

container_commands:
  00_appdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_apache_redirect_canonical.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact
  01_configdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_apache_redirect_canonical.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact
  02_rewrite_hook_perms:
    command: chmod 755 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_apache_redirect_canonical.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_apache_redirect_canonical.sh
  03_rewrite_hook_ownership:
    command: chown root:users /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_apache_redirect_canonical.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_apache_redirect_canonical.sh
```

Good luck!