# Forcing https in elasticbeanstalk with certificate from ACM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have provisioned a scalable EB(Elasticbeanstalk) rails(puma) instance. I have applied for https through ACM(Amazon Certificate Manager) and applied it to my load balancer. HTTPS is enabled for my website now. But how do I force redirect to https? I have tried a number of solutions online where it was suggested to make a nginx configuration setting manually through .ebextensions and I am not sure where to get the certificate from ACM for this?(I am assuming that is not possible with ACM right now?). How do I force HTTPS?

Comment: I followed this http://msnider.github.io/blog/2013/12/06/force-https-slash-ssl-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk/ and it worked.  You may have to manually restart your server for it to work? or maybe just uploading and deploying.  I also vaguely remember having to alias my load balancer to my domain to get my cert to work, but that could have been because I purchased an Extended Validation cert.

Comment: It seems that the Internet cannot agree on a single, complete and working solution to this problem. Hopefully you can get some help [here in my post](http://thehunk.blogspot.in/2017/11/how-to-force-redirect-http-to-https-in.html). I had to jump through hoops to come up with this, finally.

Answer (score 5):

The current AWS EB Rails and Node.js setups both use nginx (if your web server is apache see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751749/214446)), so the following should work (adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34619855)):

Create the file `.ebextensions/01-force-https.config` (the `.config` is important, not `.conf`) with the following content.

If your environment is a single instance:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-force-https.conf":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      server {
          listen 8080;
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
```

If your environment is load balanced, you unfortunately cannot simply add to the existing config but need to modify it with sed:

```
files:
  "/tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash

      CONFIGURED=`grep -c "return 301 https" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf`

      if [ $CONFIGURED = 0 ]
        then
          sed -i '/listen 80;/a \    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }\n' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf
          logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules added"
          exit 0
        else
          logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules already set"
          exit 0
      fi

container_commands:
  00_appdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact
  01_configdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact
  02_rewrite_hook_perms:
    command: chmod 755 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
  03_rewrite_hook_ownership:
    command: chown root:users /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
```

Then add it to your git repo or app bundle and `eb deploy`. This creates `/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-force-https.conf` which is automatically included from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Note that `eb deploy` won't delete the file on the server if you later remove the corresponding file from `.ebextensions`. Also, I found the following helpful in debugging through `eb ssh`:

```
sudo service nginx configtest
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: This will probably not work currently - see [my comment at your source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297375/how-to-get-elastic-beanstalk-nginx-backed-proxy-server-to-auto-redirect-from-htt#comment93464886_28271106)

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a help article for HTTP to HTTPS redirection here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html

It covers 2 main approaches, and has links to the relevant scripts you can use to do it all for you (which they maintain as they update the Elastic Beanstalk platform).