# .ebextensions not executing not uploading and creating files

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, ebextensions

I am trying to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297375/how-to-get-elastic-beanstalk-nginx-backed-proxy-server-to-auto-redirect-from-htt#answer-34619855) to force SSL on AWS Beanstalk.

I believe this is the important part.

```
files:
  "/tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash

      CONFIGURED=`grep -c "return 301 https" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf`

      if [ $CONFIGURED = 0 ]
        then
          sed -i '/listen 80;/a \    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }\n' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf
          logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules added"
          exit 0
        else
          logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules already set"
          exit 0
      fi

container_commands:
  00_appdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact
  01_configdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact
  02_rewrite_hook_perms:
    command: chmod 755 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
  03_rewrite_hook_ownership:
    command: chown root:users /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
```

For some reason the file is not being uploaded or created.

I also tried this a sudo command for the container commands starting with 00 and 01.

I also manually ssh into the server, manually created the file.  Then locally used the `aws elasticbeanstalk restart-app-server --environment-name` command to restart the server.  And this still did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may or may not work. But in AWS everthing works out by trail and error method. We need to make sure that the directories are already existing before trying to drop in the files. A blog post on this, http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/