# Enforce https connection on Rails using AWS elastic beanstalk load balancer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rails app running on puma & nginx using AWS elastic beanstalk load balancer. I configured AWS certificate and it works fine on both http and https.

However, if I enable `config.force_ssl = true` on the `config/environments/production.rb` I start getting the following errors:

On http: The connection was reset

On https: Secure Connection Failed. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Here's the content of my nginx configuration file, which I got from awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-samples [here](https://github.com/awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/ruby-puma/https-redirect-ruby-puma.config):

`.ebextensions/nginx.config`

```
files:
   "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf":
     owner: root
     group: root
     mode: "000644"
     content: |
       upstream my_app {
         server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
       }

       server {
         listen 80;
         server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

         location / {
           set $redirect 0;
           if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
             set $redirect 1;
           }
           if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
             set $redirect 0;
           }
           if ($redirect = 1) {
             return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
           }
           proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         }

         location /assets {
           alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
           gzip_static on;
           gzip on;
           expires max;
           add_header Cache-Control public;
         }

         location /public {
           alias /var/app/current/public;
           gzip_static on;
           gzip on;
           expires max;
           add_header Cache-Control public;
         }
       }

container_commands:
  99_restart_nginx:
    command: "service nginx restart || service nginx start"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found my answer elsewhere in a question related to the same problem but using Node.js

Just had to add this to a file inside .ebextensions folder, I called it enforce-ssl.config

```
files:
  "/tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash

      CONFIGURED=`grep -c "return 301 https" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf`

      if [ $CONFIGURED = 0 ]
        then
          sed -i '/listen 80;/a \    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }\n' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/webapp_healthd.conf
          logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules added"
          service nginx restart
          exit 0
        else
          logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules already set"
          exit 0
      fi

container_commands:
  00_appdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact
  01_configdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact
  02_rewrite_hook_perms:
    command: chmod 755 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
  03_rewrite_hook_ownership:
    command: chown root:users /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
```

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34619855/2454036

Update: I found out that the original answer won't always work because the nginx restart may be fired before the files are updated, so I placed the added `service nginx restart` to the script

Answer (score 0):

HTTP -> HTTPS redirection is a very common practice and AWS has documented how to achieve it here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html

The solution you have is very similar to their own provided configurations listed below, which covers a range of different environment platforms:
https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/tree/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect