# Redirect Elastic Beanstalk HTTP requests to HTTPS with nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want a redirect from HTTP request to HTTPS on Elastic Beanstalk with nginx as proxy system.

I've found a lot of advices on Google but no one helped, it doesn't redirect.

That is my current `test.config` file in `.ebexentions` directory:

```
files:
"/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        server{
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            }
        }
```

I've also tried countless other settings, none of them worked.

That are my load balancer settings:
[image]

I hope you can help me. :)

Comment: Is your EB setup with a load balancer?  Did you review everything at this SO article?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297375/how-to-get-elastic-beanstalk-nginx-backed-proxy-server-to-auto-redirect-from-htt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38420816/6523216) is the only solution that worked.

It's necessary to overwrite the default nginx file after AWS created it. So there has to be two more files:

1. Write the nginx file.
2. Create a script that overwrites the default nginx file.
3. Run the script after AWS created the default file.

Answer (score 3):

Some considerations:

**1 -** New Amazon Elastic Beanstalk platform versions running Amazon Linux 2 have a different path of reverse proxy configuration:

```
~/workspace/my-app/
|-- .platform
|   `-- nginx
|      `-- conf.d
|         `-- elasticbeanstalk
|            `-- 00_application.conf
`-- other source files
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

**2 -** The AWS ELB Health Checker appears to be unable to check HTTPS endpoints.
Surely, if you are using a custom certificate for your domain, is unable to act a check in what he considers an "untrusted site".
https://your-eb-app.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com published with a certificate registered for your organization with this DNS alias https://your-eb-app.your-organization.com causes ELB Health Checker error (certificate domain mismatch).

**3 -** The configuration suggested exposes all locations to **ANY** client which shows up with "ELB-HealthChecker*" user-agent on the standard HTTP port (80); not quite what we want :-)

You can configure ELB Health Checker to accept the HTTP 301 status, but it doesn't have much use; a simple redirect response does not mean that our web application is in good health :-)

A more secure solution is a dedicated health check endpoint configuration:

```
location / {
    set $redirect 0;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
        set $redirect 1;
    }
    if ($redirect = 1) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }   

    proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Connection         $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location = /health-check.html {
    set $redirect 0;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
        set $redirect 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
        set $redirect 0;
    }
    if ($redirect = 1) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }   

    proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Connection         $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but, if I put the 00_application.conf inside elasticbeanstalk, it is ignored completed. If I put it one level up, it is read, but it expects something different. For instance if I include "location" I get "location" directive is not allowed here in /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/00_application.conf:1. If I only include the server directive, then I get  conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored (I suppose because the server is already configured in the main nginx config).

Comment: Are you using Amazon Linux 2 platform?
These are my machine nginx file configuration paths:

[root@ip-172-99-99-55 ~]# find / -name 00_application.conf

/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf
/var/app/current/.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf
/var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem when I was trying to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS in my AWS Elastic Beanstalk Go environment using Nginx. This is the solution, I was provided by the AWS Support team:

Create a file in the below directory structure at the root of the application code.

```
.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf
```

with the content

```
location / {
    set $redirect 0;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
        set $redirect 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
        set $redirect 0;
    }
    if ($redirect = 1) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

For a complete list of AWS provided config files, you should check out [this link](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/tree/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect).

Comment: This solution did'nt work for me, after successful deployment elasticbeanstalk folder only contains two files
healthd.conf  php.conf

Comment: @AliAbbas PHP reference is at https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/php/https-redirect-php.config

Comment: Thank you it tried too many things , What i  only need inside 
nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/custom.conf

location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    gzip_static on;
}

location /blogs {
    return 301 $scheme://site.com/blog;
}
location /blogs.html {
    return 301 $scheme://site.com/blog;
}
location ~ ^/blogs/(.*) {
    return 301 $scheme://site.com/blog;
}

but I am not sure why this folder is not adding any file

Answer (score 0):

What I did to achieve , I completely override original nginx.conf with my custom given nginx.conf along with some custom configuration for location directives

`.plateform
   -- nginx
      -- nginx.conf
      -- conf.d
      -- elasticbeanstalk
          --custom.conf`

Here is my nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    32153;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  include       conf.d/*.conf;

   map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default     "upgrade";
  }
  server {
    listen        80 default_server;
    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    client_header_timeout 60;
    client_body_timeout   60;
    keepalive_timeout     60;
    gzip                  off;
    gzip_comp_level       4;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
    include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
}

}
```

Following  line will helped me to safely over-ride the configuration

`include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;`

Comment: How did you get the original nginx config, so you could safely override it?

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Beanstalk environment Load balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsW6y.jpg)

Make sure that under the load balancer settings of Beanstalk environment both the ports(80,443) enable. If the port 80 is disable you will get the error of **503** **"Service Temporarily Unavailable"**